# '$' selector in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, gulp-protractor

I have seen in many examples like this `$('.selector')` and I am also using this. So what this **$** variable does. This is what I got from the protractor [docs](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$).

> Calls to $ may be chained to find elements within a parent.

There is no example in docs which use `$` alone. We are using `$` to chain with `element` selector.

Also `$('.selector')` itself is an element, when we does this `element($('.selector'))`, it is an error.

So how to use this `$` selector in protractor. Does it have all the features of `JQuery $`. I tried `$('.selector').children` which says `children` is not a function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: $ stands for jQuery. So `$(".selector")` means all elements with class as selector.

Comment: Refer : [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Angular's built in subset of jQuery => jqLite

Comment: use angular.element instead of $, it works only on the part document of a directive and not on the entire html document

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That *looks* like jQuery syntax but it is not, it's part of Protractor.  That's why `.children` is throwing an error because we're not actually using jQuery.  `$` is a shorthanded version of `element(by.css())` i.e.

`$('my-css');` is the exact same as `element(by.css('my-css'));`

They also have `$$` which is the same as `element.all(by.css())`

Despite the lack of documentation, it does **not** *have to be used* for chaining to find child elements.  i.e. using Julie's protractor demo (I modified the example):

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('read the header', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
    $('h3').getText().then(function (val) {
      console.log(val);
    });
  });
});
```

That prints out the title of the h3 element that I located.  The `$` and `$$` are simply a shorthand for css selectors.

Source: [here for $$](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$$), [here for $](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$), and [here for more](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md)

Also this is a nice document I found (though it does not mention the use of `$$` : http://luxiyalu.com/protractor-locators-selectors/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `$('my-css')` is same as `element(by.css('my-css'))`, which is not mentioned in documentation.

Comment: Yea for some reason that's not documented on the Protractor API - and it's only mentioned once here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md

Answer (score 1):

We made updates to the Protractor's API for [$](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$). Also, there are several places in Protractor's specs that use chained $. See below (from [spec/async_spec.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/ng2/async_spec.js#L8)):

```
  it('should work with synchronous actions', function() {
    var increment = $('#increment');
    increment.$('.action').click();

    expect(increment.$('.val').getText()).toEqual('1');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct API doc for $:

"Shortcut for querying the document directly with css. `element(by.css('.abc'))` is equivalent to `$('.abc')`"

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=build$